# Apache Phoenix Illegal data. Expected length of at least 4 bytes, but had 2

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-phoenix

I have a Phoenix table created like below
[image: Phoenix Table]

And Hive External table on top of Phoenix like below

```
create External table TABLE_NAME (
rowKey STRING,
unique_id     string,
USERNAME      string,
DAY           string,
MONTH         string,
YEAR          string,
APPID         INT)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES
("hbase.columns.mapping" = "
details:unique_id,
details:USERNAME,
details:DAY,
details:MONTH,
details:YEAR,
details:APPID")
TBLPROPERTIES
("hbase.table.name"="HBAE_TABLE_NAME");
```

When I load data into hive external table and try to access APPID (Integer column) from Phoenix table, am getting below error. 
Issue is only with Integer column, rest all I am able to access fine. And data looks good when I access from hive table.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: ERROR 201 (22000): Illegal data. Expected length of at least 4 bytes, but had 2
        at sqlline.IncrementalRows.hasNext(IncrementalRows.java:73)
        at sqlline.TableOutputFormat.print(TableOutputFormat.java:33)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.print(SqlLine.java:1653)
        at sqlline.Commands.execute(Commands.java:833)
        at sqlline.Commands.sql(Commands.java:732)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.dispatch(SqlLine.java:808)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.begin(SqlLine.java:681)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.start(SqlLine.java:398)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.main(SqlLine.java:292)
```

I really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Make your each hive table column to **string**, and in phoenix views make each column to **varchar**. Issue will be resolved.
Phoenix supports Integer,Date etc. but bugs are still open, so if you want to use phoenix convert everything to string and varchar. It worked on Phoenix 4.4.0